# Vercel isn't deploying my github's project latest version

Tags: deployment, vercel, astrojs

I been using Vercel for quite a while, it's never been a headache for me until now, i'm facing a very weird situation, since yesterday it doesn't matter how many `git push` i do to my project (it only has one branch, main) Vercel keeps deploying the same old version of it. I got no errors from Vercel, it tells me it's been ok, it's deployed, but it's still an old version of my project.

ps: i'm developing a webapp using nodejs + astro, i think isn't relevant...

I'm running out of possible solutions, I've tried to delete the deployment on Vercel and create it again, nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar with my Vercel deploies. My last deploy had a function working, but the up-to-date domain didn't make it work. I asked to ChatGPT and it told me it may be a cache problem, so It recommended me to delete the browser's cache or open the up-to-date domain in an incognito window. I tried the last and, for my surprise, It did work.
I don't know if you solved it yet, but if it keeps giving you trouble, try this. It may help you.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You may need to build your frontend with "npm run build" or yarn equivalent before you push to your GitHub repository if your app is a full stack application.